# Increment an array counter

Tags: php

In the loop below I want `$value[0]` to increment on each pass of the loop. So, if `$count = 2` the loop will run twice and output `$key . " " . $value[0]` and `$key . " " . $value[1]`.

Right now, my loop is outputting `$key . " " . $value[0]` twice. What did I do wrong?

```
$count = count($updates['positionTitle']);

for($i = 1; $i<=$count; $i++){
    foreach($updates as $key => $value){
        if(!is_array($value))
           echo $key . " " . $value . "<br/>";
         else 
           echo $key . " " . $value[0]++ . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$value[0]` refers to key `0` in the array. You need `$value[$i]`.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk - Right, but that's what I want.

Comment: You are increasing `$value` which is a clone of `$updates[$key]` and will not directly edit it. Change `$key => $value` to `$key => &$value` or change `$value[0]++` to `$updates[$key]++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store what the current index is.  I'm not actually sure what loop you were talking about though.  I'm assuming it was the outer for loop.  I still think this is broken but based on your comment this is what you want.

```
$count = count($updates['positionTitle']);
$idx = 0;

for($i = 1; $i<=$count; $i++){
    foreach($updates as $key => $value){
        if(!is_array($value))
           echo $key . " " . $value . "<br/>";
         else 
           echo $key . " " . $value[$idx] . "<br/>";
    }
    $idx++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
foreach($updates as $key => $value){
```

To:

```
foreach($updates as $key => &$value){
```